# How to make a simple game in XNA?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

I want to start with a simple 2d game in xna as shown in the picture like character jumping, catching the points. Any help is appreciated. thank u.[image]

Comment: Did you tried to google "xna tutorial" ?

Comment: @OopsUser: i tried but i didn't get this kind of tutorials anywhere.

Comment: Microsoft itself provides a sample project doing exactly this.

Comment: @AlexM. Can u pls share such links ? coz i couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the [Platformer Starter Kit](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/platformer) from Microsoft. It contains a basic level system that can handle a few tiles, with basic collision. It supports enemies and "gems" by default.

[image: https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC302933.jpg]

It has quite a few problems, but that is part of the learning process, it is only designed to get you started in XNA.

You can view the documentation and enhancements [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx).